# Get current date and time as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss as a date object

Tags: date, actionscript-3, datetime

So I'm trying to get the current date and time in this format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in a Date object, not a string.

How can I do this?

Keep in mind I can't use `DateTimeFormatter`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, but you can use `DateTimeFormatter`, as it's made exactly for this purpose.

```
var df:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("");
df.setDateTimePattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
trace(df.format(new Date())); // Outputs: 2017-07-27 15:56:55
```

Is there a specific reason why this solution doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: I am using flex 3 and when I try to import it I get an error.

Comment: @Mar  Definition flash.globalization:DateTimeFormatter could not be found.

Comment: I think you need the flex version http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @Mar Mind telling me to where I'd add it? To my build .xml files?

Comment: See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html#includeExamplesSummary perhaps?